# Sending same emails to many addresses

Tags: java

Hi 
I have to send am mail(like an notification) to all the persons who fulfill some criteria.
The mail id  will be taken from the database and sent the mail

Where should I look for the implementation in **JAVA**  so that I can sent the a mail to many person.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to send email using Java: http://www.javabeat.net/tips/33-sending-mail-from-java.html

To send email to many addresses, just send the same email with different 'to' address

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the javax.mail Package

Links:
http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Message.html#addRecipient%28javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,%20javax.mail.Address%29

And as `Message.RecipientType` you should use `Message.RecipientType.BCC` to not showing the every address to every recipient

Google Keywords: Java Mail BCC

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. Assuming you know how to query the database to get the mail and recipients and how to actually send (a single) mail - it's really up to preferences.

Personally I prefer to simply put all recipients in "the BCC-field" and then actually send the mail to a dummy address or my own. That way none of the recipients will be disclosed to the others. If that is not an issue - just put 'em all in the "To-field".

(if in fact querying database and sending mail is the real issue - I'm sure there are quite a few references on this site)

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) library in an excellent Java API for sending Email. You can use the approach taken by @mbanzon to send the list by adding Bcc fields.